# PHP/MySQL Implode into multiple rows?

Tags: php, mysql, implode

is it possible to implode a checkbox value into multiple values to insert into a database?

At current I have this:

```
$tags = implode(', ', $_POST['checkboxname']);
```

This gives me the value of "testtag1, testtag2"

How would I split this up so it would go into the database like:

```
Blog ID ¦ Tag
------------------
1       ¦ testtag1

1       ¦ testtag2
```

Not sure how to make the implode function seperate them as this:

```
$query2 = mysqli_query($myConnection, "INSERT INTO blogtags (blogid, tag) VALUES('$blogid','$tags')") or die (mysqli_error($myConnection));
```

just inserts the two values together in one row.

Any help would be great!
Thanks

Comment: Why do you implode? Simply itterate through `$_POST['checkboxname']`and do an insert in each loop.

Comment: Firstly, you have a huge SQL injection hole. Secondly, think about the [MySQL syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) for inserting multiple rows in a single query - that's what you would need your string to look like. Thirdly, and most importantly because it solves both of the above and more: You should prepare a statement to insert a single row and invoke it multiple times. This is exactly what [prepared statements](http://php.net/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements) are designed for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this example:

```
$tags = $_POST['checkboxname'] ; //Take the array of tags.
$id = 1 ;                        //Set needed id.

$values = array() ;

foreach($tags as $tag){
  $tag = $myConnection->real_escape_string($tag);
  $values[] = " ('{$id}', '{$tag}') " ;
}

$values = implode(" , ", $values) ;
$query = "INSERT INTO blogtags (blogid, tag) VALUES {$values} ; " ;
```

Comment: Saving comma-separated values in a database is often a bad idea. A better option is to save a different record for each tag.

Comment: @Jocelyn If you run this code, you will see, that it makes different records for each tag.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. I had seen `implode` and implied you were imploding the tags. Using multi-insert as you do is fine. I should have read the code more carefully.